# TinyMCE - Change default background color

Tags: jquery, css, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE editor.
Everything works perfectly, but when I save the content of textarea editor, it saves the content with a default background-color:#fff and when I show it on a page with a non-white background color, appears like this:

[image]

I'm using thi initialization of TinyMCE:

```
tinymce.init({
selector: '.full-featured',
plugins: 'searchreplace autolink directionality visualblocks visualchars image link media template codesample table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor toc insertdatetime advlist lists wordcount imagetools textpattern help',
toolbar: 'formatselect | bold italic strikethrough forecolor backcolor permanentpen formatpainter | link image media pageembed | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify  | numlist bullist outdent indent | removeformat | addcomment',
height: 400,
image_caption: true,
fontsize_formats: "8pt 10pt 12pt 14pt 18pt 24pt 36pt 42pt 48pt",
font_formats: "",
invalid_styles: 'margin margin-top margin-right margin-bottom margin-left width font-family'
});
```

It's possible setting a default transparent background-color for every TinyMCE content saved?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/theme-development/2006-11-16/how-do-you-apply-your-themes-background-color-to-tinymce#:~:text=By%20default%20TinyMCE%20has%20a,pain%20to%20say%20the%20least.) helps

Comment: Based on the configuration you are using to initialize TinyMCE I would not expect TinyMCE (on its own) to inject inline styles like that on content.  What are you doing during the content editing process that applies these inline styles?

Comment: Are you pasting in content into TinyMCE? Formatting (and styles) are often preserved when copying and pasting nowadays.